# How do I add the includes for SDL 2 to Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, header, sdl-2

I would like to use Eclipse to write some programs in C using the SDL 2 library.
I'm now extremely frustrated, as no matter what I do, even using the exact path for the header file 'SDL.h' results in Eclipse spitting out that the functions are undefined.
What do I need to put, and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't state which OS but see these tutorials:

- http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-eclipse-osx/
- http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-eclipse-windows/
- http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/ (old but concept still correct)
- http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/linux/ (old but concept still correct)

Comment: I apologize; I'm using Linux. I thought it'd be OS independent.

Comment: I suppose this answers the question I asked.

Comment: @Torger597 - Try this - http://avedo.net/789/installing-sdl2-with-eclipse-cdt-under-linux sorry I don't have much Linux experience.